# Setting the primary display

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop that the screen is broken and there isn't any way to see main display. So, I use a seccond monitor. I remember, first day I decided to use my seccond, I had to change the output (I mean main display) in the intel setting. Fortunately, graphic settings window was visble in both displays :)))
Now, the problem is I can't install xubuntu with this problem; Because I can't see the taskbar in live-mode (I'm new and I don't know the name, Sorry) and I can't see the window that we create partions with. So, the question is: Is there any way to change main display while installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you could xrandr in the commandline... The only thing you need to know is the name of the monitor you'd like to connect to... 
Open a terminal and execute xrandr:

```
xrandr -q
```

The answer will look like:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 190mm
   1440x900      60.06*+  50.18  
   1400x900      59.88  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.81    60.00    59.91  
   1280x720      59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      59.90    59.82  
   960x540       59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   720x450       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300mm
   1280x1024     75.02* 
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00  
   640x480       75.00
```

Since LVDS1 is the default monitor for a laptop the other

> VGA1 connected

is the external one (in my example- yours is probably another). Only the monitors that are "connected" are available!

Now execute

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --primary --auto
```

and the attached monitor will have the task bar. If you want to completely turn off your broken "primary screen" you could execute:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --primary --auto --output LVDS1 --off
```

Please note that VGA1 and LVDS1 are examples from my old thinkpad. You need to replace them with the  monitors from the xrandr list.

This will not work on wayland, but usually the X session should be active during installation...

Comment: Worked! THANKS A LOT

Comment: Just another question: How can I save this change for ever?

Comment: /etc/X11/org.conf.d/ ..: Add a monitor conf and a device conf.:

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Option      "Monitor-EIZO" "VGA"
    Driver      "intel"
EndSection

Just as an example. There is a lot of documentation about setting up monitors. Some even say you could do it in the GDM - but I've never got it to run. Example above works...