# External screen can function but not the built-in screen of my laptop

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, screen, nvidia-optimus

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. When I connect to external screen and boost the ubuntu, the external screen can display, however the built-in screen remains in active black.

I still be able to drag the apps to the built-in one, thus I suspect it still functions but just not able to display. My laptop is ZenBook-UX431FN with Intel UHD Graphics 620 and GeForce MX 150 which builds on top of NVIDIA Optimus. I believe that's the cause of the trouble.

Can anyone help letting these two screens function? Thanks a lot.

Edit:
Both monitors can be detected NVIDIA X Server as prime display, I can  not adjust them.

Comment: did you install any drivers, such as NVIDIA? Then use the NVIDIA settings. Otherwise would [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1224780/906933) answer help you?

Comment: I have used NVIDIA driver and the setting, so I don't think that the issue is. I will try another method and get back to you. Thanks a lot !